# Richtextbox change the flow direction when the language change( AR/ENG) C#

Tags: c#, wpf, richtext

I have a richtextbox and I would like to change dynamically the flow direction of the text when I click on `alt+shift` to change from the Arabic language to the English language ( the flow direction should be changed from `RightToLeft` to `LefttoRight` ).

Is this possible using .Net libraries?

```
  private void RichText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var factory = new RankedLanguageIdentifierFactory();
        try
        {
            var identifier = factory.Load("Core14.profile.xml");
            // can be an absolute or relative path. Beware of 260 chars limitation of the path length in Windows. Linux allows 4096 chars.
            string text = new TextRange(RichText.Document.ContentStart, RichText.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
            var languages = identifier.Identify(text);
            var mostCertainLanguage = languages.FirstOrDefault();
            if (mostCertainLanguage != null)
                if ((mostCertainLanguage.Item1.Iso639_3.Equals("eng")) || (mostCertainLanguage.Item1.Iso639_3.Equals("fra")))
                {
                    RichText.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                }
                else if (mostCertainLanguage.Item1.Iso639_3.Equals("dan"))
                {
                    RichText.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;

                }
        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception    " + es);
        }
    }
```

This what I have tried using this Nuget package [ntextcat library](https://github.com/ivanakcheurov/ntextcat)

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it

```
 string lang =InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage.ToString();
            string langtwo = lang.Substring(0, 3);

                if (langtwo.Equals("ar-")) 
                {
                    RichText.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
                }
    
                else
                {
                    RichText.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                }
```

I followed this documentation:

- [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputlanguagemanager.currentinputlanguage?view=net-5.0](http://InputLanguageManager.CurrentInputLanguage%20Property)